# Simple analog to second harmonic generation

Tags: non-linear-optics

I have been trying to explain second harmonic generation to my mum who is hopeless at physics. Does anyone know of a good simple analog for second harmonic generation? Preferably something that is classical and easy to visualize (springs and pendula etc); even better if I can code sort of visual simulation of it.

Comment: Not really, since it depends on a nonlinear response to stimulus.   Would she be satisified with a demonstration that a vibrating string (guitar/violin-ish) can produce a fundamental tone and support the first octave? That's not SHG but it might be enough.

Comment: Thanks, that's more or less what I have been going with. By simple, I meant something no too abstract to understand but that is governed by a similar set of coupled nonlinear equations.